# Stopping express reloading the page on route change

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, mithril.js

I need to stop express refreshing the page when the route changes on my client side. I am using the MVC framework Mithril.js to handle my client side routing as it does not need to refresh the page when the route changes. I am using express for my /api routes. Here is my current routing code on the server side:

```
var assetFolder = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/public')
routes.use(express.static(assetFolder))


if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  routes.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile( assetFolder + '/index.html' )
  });
  app.use('/', routes)
}
```

Even with this routing code, when I change routes on the client side the page still refreshes in between. Is there a way to stop this happening? Note: I am using the pathname route mode with mithril as that is what I need for my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace `app.use('/', routes)` with `app.use('*', routes)` basically you would want to render the index.html file for all routes.
OR try this it should work

```
var assetFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile( assetFolder + '/index.html' );
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do but as soon as I do it my app stops working on the client side. Nothing renders?

Comment: what is `routes`? Add more information. I have used something like this in angular configurations and it works

var assetFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile( assetFolder + '/index.html' );
});